# which algorithm perform better for high dimensional feature and small sample size?

Tags: algorithm, dimension

I am trying my best to deal with high-dimensional data in a small sample size. For an example, Y is 500*1 matrix and X is 500*10000 matrix. Are there some better regression methods for this data?

Comment: off-topic. This belongs to the stats.stackexchange.com. However even for that board this question is way too broad. You need to get more specific!

Answer (score 1):

An applicable solution is to apply some reduction methods such as PCA (principal component analysis) over `X` and apply the regression over the result of PCA.